# Consulta de reseñas a Google My Business API con PHP

Tags: php, api

Tengo este código PHP:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Carga el autoloader de Composer

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

// Configuración de las credenciales de OAuth 2.0
$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$redirect_uri = 'XXXXXXXXX';

// ID de la localización de Google My Business
$location_id = 'XXXXXXXXX'; // Cambia esto con el ID de tu localización

// URL para obtener el token de acceso
$authorization_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
$token_url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

// Inicializar el cliente Guzzle
$client = new Client();

try {
    // Si se ha recibido el código de autorización
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        // Intercambiar el código de autorización por un token de acceso
        $code = $_GET['code'];

        $response = $client->post($token_url, [
            'form_params' => [
                'code' => $code,
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            ],
        ]);

        // Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa
        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

            // El token de acceso estará en $data['access_token']
            $access_token = $data['access_token'];

            // URL para obtener las reseñas de Google My Business
            $reviews_url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{$client_id}/locations/{$location_id}/reviews";

            // Obtener las reseñas utilizando Guzzle
            $reviews_response = $client->get($reviews_url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);

            // Verificar si la solicitud de reseñas fue exitosa
            if ($reviews_response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
                // Decodificar la respuesta JSON de las reseñas
                $reviews_data = json_decode($reviews_response->getBody(), true);

                // Imprimir las reseñas
                if (isset($reviews_data['reviews'])) {
                    foreach ($reviews_data['reviews'] as $review) {
                        echo "Reseña de {$review['reviewer']['displayName']}: {$review['comment']['text']}\n";
                        echo "Puntuación: {$review['starRating']}\n";
                        echo "Fecha: {$review['createTime']}\n\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No se encontraron reseñas.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error al obtener reseñas. HTTP Status Code: {$reviews_response->getStatusCode()}\n";
                echo "Response Body: {$reviews_response->getBody()}\n";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error en la solicitud de token. HTTP Status Code: {$response->getStatusCode()}\n";
            echo "Response Body: {$response->getBody()}\n";
        }
    } else {
        // Si no se ha recibido el código de autorización, redirigir al usuario a la URL de autorización
        $auth_url = "$authorization_url?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage";
        header("Location: $auth_url");
        exit;
    }
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo "Error en la solicitud: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo "HTTP Status Code: " . $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() . "\n";
        echo "Response Body: " . $e->getResponse()->getBody() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, muestra este error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXX"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "mybusiness.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "projects/XXXXXXXXX"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Si sigo el enlace del error, esta es la respuesta:

*No se pudo cargar la página.
Se produjo un error durante la carga de /apis/library/mybusiness.googleapis.com?project=serious-amulet-405519. Vuelve a intentarlo.
Es posible que se trate de un problema con el navegador o la red. Ve a la página de ayuda sobre los problemas de carga  para solucionarlos.
ID de solicitud: 8432217666173142776*

Aparentemente, la configuración de la clave API, OAuth 2.0, cuenta de servicio, permisos del proyecto... es correcta.

¿Dónde puede estar el error?

Comment: Creaste el proyecto en la consola de google api ?

Comment: Creo que sí, pero no estoy seguro si lo he hecho en el sitio correcto. Dentro de https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard arriba hay un select que tiene un proyecto "My Proyect XXX". Una vez seleccionado este, están la API KEY y los otros datos que estoy usando.